# Passing data from one web-page to other page, how to do this?

Tags: html, servlets

Suppose I am going to create a web page with two box, for entering the user id and user password respectively. And then once i click the submit button, it will check with the database in background whether this user exist. If it matches anyone in the database, the user id and user password will be forwarded to the other page, at the same time it will redirect to that user's main page.

Can I just use servlet to complete this task?

I found there is request.Dispatcher API but is it enough for the task?

```
String name = "Tom" 
request.setAttribute("name",name); 

RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher 
("Servlet2"); 

request.Forward(request,response);
```

in second servlet file

```
request.getAttribute("name"); 
//this line will display "Tom"
```

One more question to ask, how about clicking a link (INSTEAD OF BUTTON) to pass some data and redirect to other servlet pages? Any idea? Many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a servlet for this. Whether the dispatcher is enough or not depends on the concrete functional requirements which are not fully clear from your question. The canonical approach, however, is to store the logged-in user in the session scope instead of in the request scope. Otherwise the user has to login everytime the user want to visit a restricted page.

Also, you normally would like to send a redirect after the login succeeds. This way the new URL get reflected in browser's address bar. Also this way pressing F5 afterwards won't cause any possible surprises. Forwarding from one to another servlet is at its own also somewhat a design smell. Including would have been reasonable, but forwarding not. As said, send a redirect instead.

As to using a link to submit a form, just execute JS `form.submit()` during the click event.

```
<form id="login">
    ...
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('login').submit(); return false;">login</a>
</form>
```

An alternative is to style the button to look like a link with a little help of CSS. This way it'll also work on clients who have JS disabled (for example, the handheld users).